# Split a Specified string into Date

Tags: c#, string, datetime

My string Is like 10130060/**151015**/0017164

want to convert the bold part of string into date
i.e `15/10/2015`

Comment: `151015`..Cant it be `15/10/1915` or `15/10/2115`?

Comment: Indeed - what would 190676 mean?

Comment: Where are you stuck?  What have you tried that isn't working as expected?  Splitting a string and parsing a date are fairly straightforward things, each of which have many examples to be found online.

Comment: @rahul : the year part is by default for this century only ie. 20

Comment: @AkhilRJ:- Did you check the answer below. See why it matters? Quoting from the answer itself `That's why your 15 will be parsed as 2015 but 76 will be parsed as 1976.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not completely clear but when you say *with bold part,* if you mean *always* between first `/` and second `/` characters, you can split your string with `/` and you can parse it to `DateTime` with [`ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact.aspx) method.

```
var s = "10130060/151015/0017164";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s.Split('/')[1], "ddMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt); // 15/10/2015
```

But remember, as others commented, since you need to use [`yy` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx?#yySpecifier), this specifier uses supplied culture [`Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax.aspx).

> This property allows a 2-digit year to be properly translated to a
>   4-digit year. For example, if this property is set to 2029, the
>   100-year range is from 1930 to 2029. Therefore, a 2-digit value of 30
>   is interpreted as 1930, while a 2-digit value of 29 is interpreted as
>   2029.

For `InvariantCulture`, it's set to `2029`. That's why your `15` will be parsed as `2015` but `76` will be parsed as `1976`.

By the way, my solution does not work *if* your single day and month numbers does not have a [leading zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading_zero) like `51015` or `15515`. In such cases, you need to use `d` and/or `M` format specifiers instead.

> thanx for the answer but the problem is this data is feeded by the
>   user at run time and it will be in the format ddmmyy , the year part
>   is fixed it will be for this century only.

First of all, `mm` and `MM` specifiers are not same. `mm` specifier is for minutes but `MM` specifier is for months. All [custom date and time specifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are case sensitive.

If you always wanna parse your two digit years in 21st century, you can [`Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone.aspx) a culture that uses Gregorian Calendar as a `Calendar` property like `InvariantCulture`, set it's `TwoDigitYearMax` property to `2099`, and use *that* cloned culture when you parse your string.

```
var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
clone.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 2099;
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s.Split('/')[1], "ddMMyy", clone);
```

Your `151015` will parse as `15/10/2015` and your `151076` parsed as `15/10/2076`.

Comment: thanx for the answer but the problem is this data is feeded by the user at run time  and it will be in the format ddmmyy , the year part is fixed it will be for this century only

Comment: @AkhilRJ Update my answer based on your comment. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I would split the string bit for bit. Here is a function that returns a string array. Each string would have the same length.

```
    public static string[] SplitBitforBit(string text, int bitforbit)
    {
        int splitcount = Convert.ToInt32(RoundAt(text.Length / bitforbit, 0, 0));
        char[] allChars = text.ToCharArray();
        string[] splitted = new string[splitcount];
        int iL = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i != splitted.Length; i++)
        {
            splitted[i] = null;
            for (int j = 0; j != bitforbit; j++)
            {
                splitted[i] += allChars[iL];
                iL++;
            }
        }
        return splitted;
    }
```

The RoundAt-method will round up automatically if you set Position and startUp to 0:

```
    public static double RoundAt(double Number, int Position, int startUp)
    {
        double Up = Math.Abs(Number) * Math.Pow(10, Position);
        double temp = Up;
        double Out;
        while (Up > 0)
        {
            Up--;
        }
        Out = temp - Up;                           //Up
        if (Up < (Convert.ToDouble(startUp) - 10) / 10)
        { Out = temp - Up - 1; }                   //Down
        if (Number < 0)
        { Out *= -1; }
        Out /= Math.Pow(10, Position);
        return Out;
    }
```

Example:

```
        string yourString = "171115";
        string[] splitted = SplitBitforBit(yourString, 2);
        int day = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[0]);
        int month = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[1]);
        int year = 2000 + Convert.ToInt32(splitted[2]);//!!! just for years since 2000
        DateTime yourDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        Console.WriteLine(yourDate);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: _Well_, don't you think those `int` parsing + `Math` methods + `double` parsing is little bit ehm.. complicated for _only_ splitting this string? I think your some calculations are _quite_ unnecessary for such a basic process. (no offense)

Comment: The RoundAt-method is just a method which was used original for an other purpose, but you can use it to round numbers in a different way (Don't want to explain it furher...) . In this case I needed to round up my result and I wrote it not just for splitting, but it can be used here. Apart from this you're right.